# Sort data by Sum from 2 fields and Sort Descending

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with this document in `MongoDB`

```
string _id;
string item;
string category;
int mobileView;
int webView;
```

I want to take 10 items sorted descending by the total sum of `mobileView` and `webView`, is there anyway I can achieve this directly just by querying, or should I get all the data and loop through it all and sum the `mobileView` and `webView` manually before taking only the 10 with highest total?

I've been reading about the `Aggregation Framework`, but from what I understand, it `Sum` only one field that's been grouped by the query. Did what I understand is wrong, if so how to do it using the `Aggregation Framework`.

(I don't want the total `Sum` of the `View` to be grouped by the same `category`, I need it to only `Sum` the `View` on each item before sort it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aggregation framework is what you want here. Not only for "aggregating" but for "manipulation" of documents as well. So basically you want the [**`$add`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) operator and the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) pipeline to get your desired result.

Will take me a few moments to fire up a Visual Studio, so here is the shell form that is not hard to translate:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "item": 1,
        "category": 1,
        "mobileView": 1,
        "webView": 1,
        "totalView": { "$add": [ "$mobileView", "$webView" ] }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "totalView": -1 } }
])
```

So basically "calculate" a field and then use that "projected" result as the field to [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) on.

Just BSON documents, so it should not be to hard.

Specifically for C# syntax do something like this:

```
var project = new BsonDocument {
    {
        "$project",
        new BsonDocument()
            .Add( "item", 1 )
            .Add( "category", 1 )
            .Add( "mobileView", 1 )
            .Add( 
                "totalView",
                new BsonDocument()
                    .Add( "$add", new BsonArray {
                        "$mobileView", "$webView"
                    })
            )
    } 
};

var sort = new BsonDocument {
    {
        "$sort",
        new BsonDocument {
            { "totalView", -1 }
        }
    }
};

var pipeline = new[] { project, sort };
var results = collection.Aggregate(pipeline);
```

All of the **`$project`** items just as with **`$group`** are "explicitly" named fields to include in the stage output. In the aggregation framework, the fields you want are "all or nothing" and you must specify each one you expect to be visible in the next pipeline stage or indeed at the end of the pipeline. Fields not mentioned no longer exist as far as the pipeline is concerned.

Think unix style "pipe" `|` where you "chain" results of one command to another, which is a clear analogy for what is happening here.

Comment: what is the meaning for `"$project"` and `1` in each attribute in the document? should I create a new `BsonDocument` like in [here](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c/). Then using the Aggregate for example like this? `var results = collection.Aggregate(project).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("TotalView")).SetLimit(10).ToList();`

Comment: @Kyojimaru The "pipeline" stages which is everything inside [] is an individual BSON document. So the argument to `Aggregate` is a "list" of BSON documents. The LINQ methods don't apply here as everything is specified in "pipeline". I can try to get there with a succinct example if it's too hard to understand right now. As I said, will need to free space and start up a Visual Studio to confirm syntax. So it takes me a few moments to express in something I do not always do.

Comment: I think I've got the idea of how to use it now after using the `MongoVue`, still can't convert to use the syntax on the `C#` though. Gonna read more on how to write the syntax properly inside the `C#` tommorow morning, and thanks for the guidance. Will be really appreciated though if you can confirm the syntax in the `C#`

Comment: @Kyojimaru Something C# "ish" added. Which off the top of my head looks about right but no chance to verify as yet.

Comment: great, it's working perfectly. If I have about 5000 items in my collection, and I want to take only 10, is it ok to go with your `code` without specifying the total items to be taken, or should I specify it to take only 10?

Comment: @Kyojimaru See [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) specifically and the other [aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) available as well for further reference. Worthwhile getting to know them. One day this might translate to LINQ. Various discussions on this, but it is yet to reach a consensus to a definitive representation.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a Linq provider, [MongoLinqPlusPlus](https://bitbucket.org/tomAdomic/mongolinqplusplus), to generate simple aggregation framework pipelines such as yours.

So with MongoLinqPlusPlus your query simply becomes:

```
collection.QueryablePlusPlus()
          .Select(c => new {
              OriginalDoc = c,
              SortKey = c.mobileView + c.webView
          })
          .OrderByDescending(c => c.SortKey)
          .Take(10)
          .Select(c => c.OriginalDoc)
```

(* It would be nice if we could do the arithmetic in the sort (.OrderByDescending(c => c.mobileView + c.webView) but the aggregation framework doesn't support this directly.  So I chose to require the developer the explicitly create the projection rather than have it implicitly created by the Linq provider.)